# Apache Open Office installation

Tags: apache2, 21.10, openoffice.org

I have a problem whene I trying install Apache Open Office on ubuntu 21.10.
I runned this commande on terminal "~/Desktop/en-US/DEBS$ sudo dpkg -i * .deb"
The result was "dpkg: error: archive 'desktop-integration' is not a regular file"

Comment: Try removing the space between * and .deb ...

Comment: Yes, It works, Thank you verry much.